# Why does a redirectPermanent after a Last RewriteRule works?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With this `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RedirectPermanent /test/ /test2/
```

This url `http://www.example.com/test/` should first pass through the Wordpress dispatcher's `RewriteRule` and stop at `. /index.php [L]` because of the `[L]`.

So why does the RedirectPermanent condition after that is working ? When I enter the previous url I'm redirected to `http://www.example.com/test2/`.

How does Apache handle this kind of redirection ?

Comment: > "The `[L]` flag causes `mod_rewrite` to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed." `RedirectPermanent` is provided by `mod_alias` and not `mod_rewrite`

Comment: Ok I understand, could you please give me a related official source link from apache in an answer ? I can't find this information online.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @hjpotter92 comment.

The `[L]` flag only affects rules set by `mod_rewrite`.

`RedirectPermanent` depends on `mod_alias` therefore it will not be affected by `[L]` flags put on `mod_rewrite` rules.

- [`[L]` flag documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)
- [`RedirectPermanent` documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent)